# How to create a graph network (Networkx) from the solution of Ordinary differential equations?

Tags: graphs, scipy, graph-neural-network, networkx

I have a list of Nodes.

```
Suppose,
N =["1","2","3","4"] # there can be different number of nodes
```

And I have solved the differential equation which is a relation to anything(let us consider)
using `odeint`

From the solution of the differential equation, I have the relation between C and t

```
result = odeint(model,C0,t)
```

Now, assuming the edges are created from the solution of the differential equation between C and t. I want to create a graph network using Networkx.

Is there any way to retrieve edges from the differential equation? So, that I can create a graph network.

Comment: I fail to understand what is asked. If you have the solution can't you sample it and have a grid that represents a path or a graph?